# Adding a date to my MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I was wondering if anyone could help me add a dynamic date to my database. The idea is I want to sort the database by people who have registered. So below I have a user schema of the values my database holds I have tried different things like adding a variable that holds a date object but no luck. I have tried searching around with no clear answer. Is there someone that can help me out?

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
firstName: {type: String, required: true, validate: nameValidator},
lastName: {type: String, required: true, validate: nameValidator},
addressOne: {type: String, required: true, validate: addressValidator},
addressTwo: {type: String, validate: addressValidator},
city: {type: String, required: true, validate: cityValidator},
state: {type: String, required: true, validate: stateValidator},
zipcode: {type: String, required: true, validate: zipValidator},
country: {type: String, required: true, validate: countryValidator},
});
```

Comment: You want to sort records by the date of registration of users ?

Comment: yes, more specifically sorted in descending order by date of registration

Comment: I think the easiest option is: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps  `new Schema({ timestamps: true });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify date datatype using `Date`. All supported data types can be found [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
      firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate: nameValidator
      },
      lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate: nameValidator
      },
      registrationDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: false,
        default: Date.now
      }
);
```

Above code will also give `registrationDate` as current time of saving `userSchema` by default.